# Configuring OpenCPU with a subdomain

Tags: nginx, opencpu

I've been working up several opencpu apps (which I love!).

My server is local and I have full control over it.

Currently I access my apps though something like:

mydomain.com/ocpu/library/packageName/www

However, I would like to create a subdomain and route it to the app like:

appname.mydomain.com

Setting up the subdomain to route to the server isn't a problem... but where do I go from there?

Comment: Have a look at the nginx configs for opencpu-cache and ocpu.io: https://github.com/jeroenooms/opencpu-server/tree/master/opencpu-cache

Comment: so should I just add another location under opencpu-cache/nginx/opencpu.d/ocpu.conf ?